# Grid ItemSize is smaller than expected

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

If I execute `MatrixPlot@IdentityMatrix@100`, the result is a good size. However, if I evaluate

```
Grid[{{200!}, {MatrixPlot@IdentityMatrix@100}}, ItemSize -> Automatic]
```

the `MatrixPlot` is much smaller, even when the page is wide. How can I make the `MatrixPlot` appear at its original size in the `Grid`? I'd prefer not to hard-code the size.

[image: this picture]

The picture shows that the second `MatrixPlot` is too small.

Comment: `Automatic != Automatic` so why not just use `ImageSize` for `MatrixPlot`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you set `ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1` then the graphics will not be downsized when appear inside list-like constructs:

```
Style[
     Grid[{{200!}, {MatrixPlot@IdentityMatrix@100}}, ItemSize -> Automatic],   
     ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

Alternatively,

```
Grid[{{200!}, {MatrixPlot@IdentityMatrix@100}}, ItemSize -> Automatic,
  BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

or

```
Grid[{{200!}, {MatrixPlot@IdentityMatrix@100}}, ItemSize -> Automatic,
  ItemStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

give the same output.

Answer (score 5):

Although he puts it somewhat obliquely, Kuba is giving you good advice in his comment. When you place a graphics object into a `Grid` or `Column` construct and care even a little about its size, explicitly make the setting of the `ImageSize` option in the graphics object.

[image: notebook.png]