# Ugly output when combining 2 plots with GraphicsRow

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

Here are the data that I want to plot:

```
meandatf1 = Mean /@ datf1
meandatf2 = Mean /@ datf2

{1.48908, 1.49641, 1.49354, 1.50385, 1.49835, 1.49617, 1.50569, \
1.50117, 1.50226, 1.50151, 1.50108, 1.50031, 1.49955, 1.49721, \
1.49898, 1.50266, 1.50177, 1.50227, 1.49886, 1.50002}

{-0.00127783, 0.000556012, 0.0000143709, -0.000602328, -0.000375952, \
-0.00125357, 0.0000228143, 0.000175103, 0.000868018, -0.0003298, \
0.000230178, 0.000222689, -0.0000624273, -0.0000760139, -0.000263302, \
0.0000826082, 0.000206463, 0.0000507921, -0.0000955452, 0.000184107}
```

And here is how I generate my individual plots:

```
genPlot[c_, dat_, ymin_, ymax_, legend_] :=
 ListPlot[{
   Table[c, {Length[dat]}], dat},
   AxesLabel -> {"N", "\[Mu]"}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {ymin, ymax}},
   PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Above],
   Joined -> True, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
   ImageSize -> 400] (* I tried also without ImageSize, see below *)

plot1 = genPlot[3/2, meandatf1,  1.45,  1.55,  "\[ScriptCapitalD]1"]
plot2 = genPlot[0,   meandatf2, -0.004, 0.004, "\[ScriptCapitalD]2"]
```

The output of the individual plots is fine:

[image]

But when I combine the two plots with `GraphicsRow[]` I get this ugly output:

[image]

When I don't specify `ImageSize` in `genPlot[]` the combined plot is very small (but otherwise looks fine):

[image]

If I set `ImageSize` in the `GraphicsRow[]` (and not in `genPlot[]`) the container image is increased instead of the contained cells (which is reasonable, but was a desperate long shot by my side):

[image]

It must be something trivial that I am missing. Any ideas?

**EDIT1**: I am using *Mathematica* 9.0.1 under Mac OSX Mavericks.

**EDIT2**: Pretty much all of the proposed solutions worked for me. I wish I could accept >1 but, since this is not possible, I'll accept the one from @JasonB for its beauty of simplicity.

Comment: I believe the minimal and best solution is [per my suggestion here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162884/53366).  Does it work for you?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`GraphicsRow`, `GraphicsGrid`, or `GraphicsColumn` can be useful, when you need the output to be a `Graphics` object.  But it's often easier to just use the corresponding non-`Graphics` version; I find the resizing and spacing options easier to use.

When I do

```
Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}]
```

I get
[image]

which I think is what you want.

Comment: Did you manually resize the grid @JasonB? I thought that `Grid[]` worked for me, but the resultant image is very small and I have to manually resize it.

Comment: @Zet See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34756/280) on how to prevent downsizing of graphics inside `Grid`.

Comment: Inspired by this very nice solution, I tried `Row[{plot1,plot2}]`, which seems nice as well on the screen. But when `Export` this `Row` as an image file, it could automatically become a column-like thing (maybe too wide?). But `Grid` works fine... Anyone happen to know why?

Comment: @xiaohuamao that is a good question, and this site probably has the answer somewhere if we can figure out how to ask the question. When you export to an image file, it has to rasterize the expression; also `Row` does some line breaking (try `Row[Range[500]]`). Try setting an `ImageSize` option when you export, or a `PlotSize` for the plots.  If all else fails ask it here and someone will answer or find the duplicate.

Answer (score 13):

You can often get tolerable results from the likes of `GraphicsColumn` by specifying explicit values for `ImagePadding`, making sure you allow enough padding for frame or axis labels.

Here's a stacked plot using `GraphicsColumn`:

```
commonopts = {Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> All,
    PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.4, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", 12}};

a = ListLinePlot[{meandatf1, 1.5 + 0 meandatf1}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"N", "\[Mu]", Style["GraphicsColumn - not a total disaster", Bold, 14]}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{70, 20}, {0, 40}}, 
   Epilog -> Text["D1", Scaled[{0.95, 0.9}]], commonopts];

b = ListLinePlot[{meandatf2, 0 meandatf2}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"N", "\[Mu]"}, ImagePadding -> {{70, 20}, {40, 0}}, 
   Epilog -> Text["D2", Scaled[{0.95, 0.9}]], commonopts];

GraphicsColumn[{a, b}, Center, 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I am rather aghast at how poor those solutions are! Are the two sets of data suppose to be related? They have the same horizontal range so why not put them on top of each other and have only one x axis? Then it is really poor technique to use an Axis plot when the data is crossing the axis. The ticks and labels clobber the data! Look in a journal such as Science and see how many such Axes plots you can find! Then the "mean" line probably should not have been drawn with ListPlot. It is better to draw it separately and use Style to turn off Antialiasing to obtain a sharp line.

Also, I would not too quickly get into writing routines such as genPlot. In a case like this it is better to produce a graphic first by working with the individual elements and doing a lot of perfecting and then, if you are going to produce many such plots, write a routine.

In any case, here is a graphic I produced using the Presentations Application, which I sell for $50. It is an application designed to aid in the production of custom graphics, tables, dynamic presentations, and generally literate notebooks. It has a number of essays on using Mathematica and numerous examples. It is 38 MB in size and has 511 files.

Some of the Presentation routines used here are:

XTickLine and YTickLine for producing free standing scales.

YAxisBreak for producing a broken y axis.

Aliasing as a convenient methods for producing sharp horizontal and vertical lines.

TranslateOp and ScaleOp as convenient post-op commands for graphics transformations.

The ability to freely mix curves and graphics primitives, just drawing one thing after another.

The graphic might be further improved but I don't know enough about what the data represents.

In this approach I am simply drawing on a piece of paper and using scaling and translation to position the curves.

```
<< Presentations`
Draw2D[
 {YTickLine[{0, 4, -0.01}, {-0.0015, 0.0010}, {-0.001, 0.0010, 0.001},
    5],
  YAxisBreak[5, 2, 0.2, 0.2],
  YTickLine[{6, 10, -0.01}, {1.48, 1.51}, {1.48, 1.51, 0.01}, 5],
  XTickLine[{0, 20, -0.2}, {0, 20}, {0, 20, 5}, 5],
  (* Draw the second set *)
  {Aliasing@Draw[0, {x, 0, 20}],
     ListDraw[meandatf2,
      Joined -> True, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Thick,
      InterpolationOrder -> 0]} // ScaleOp[{1, 1600}, {0, 0}] // 
   TranslateOp[{0, 2.4}],
  (* Draw the first set *)
  {Aliasing@Draw[3/2, {x, 0, 20}],
     ListDraw[meandatf1,
      Joined -> True, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Thick,
      InterpolationOrder -> 0]} // ScaleOp[{1, 400/3}, {0, 0}] // 
   TranslateOp[{0, -191.33}],
  (* Add Labels *)
  Text["\[ScriptCapitalD]1", {13, 10}],
  Text["\[ScriptCapitalD]2", {15, 3.5}],
  Text["Sample Points", {10, -2}],
  Text[Style["Graphical Presentation Matters", 14, Bold], {10, 12}]},
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 Frame -> False, Axes -> False,
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 21}, {-3, 13}},
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: **Pesentation Matters**, but spelling not so much...  Nice output though :-)

Comment: Nice demo of the Presentations package, which I never knew existed.

Comment: Sorry about the spelling. I was doing it in the middle of the night and have corrected it.

Answer (score 7):

@DavidPark's answer is high quality, extremely well thought out and typical of the care he takes putting together graphics which are designed to display the data in their best light.

An alternative to his `Presentations` package is `LevelScheme`.  The code below is one graphic that might be produced using this free package.

```
Needs["LevelScheme`LevelScheme`"]
Block[
 {},
 md1 = {1.48908, 1.49641, 1.49354, 1.50385, 1.49835, 1.49617, 1.50569,
    1.50117, 1.50226, 1.50151, 1.50108, 1.50031, 1.49955, 1.49721, 
   1.49898, 1.50266, 1.50177, 1.50227, 1.49886, 1.50002};

 md2 = {-0.00127783, 0.000556012, 
   0.0000143709, -0.000602328, -0.000375952, -0.00125357, 
   0.0000228143, 0.000175103, 0.000868018, -0.0003298, 0.000230178, 
   0.000222689, -0.0000624273, -0.0000760139, -0.000263302, 
   0.0000826082, 0.000206463, 0.0000507921, -0.0000955452, 
   0.000184107};
 {mnx, mxx} = {1, Length@md1};
 {ny1, xy1} = {Min@md1, Max@md1};
 {ny2, xy2} = {Min@md2, Max@md2};
 Figure[{
   SetOptions[SchemeObject, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 10],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .97}, "Comparison", FontSize -> 12, 
    FontWeight -> Bold, Offset -> {0, 0}],
   Multipanel[{2, 1},
    Margin -> 50,
    XPlotRanges -> {mnx, mxx},
    YPlotRanges -> {{1.4, 1.6}, {-.002, .002}},
    XFrameLabels -> {"N"}, BufferB -> 5,
    YFrameLabels -> {"\[Mu]", "\[Mu]"}, BufferL -> 10,
    XFrameTicks -> {LinTicks[1, 20, 2, 2]},
    YFrameTicks -> {
      LinTicks[1.4, 1.6, .05, 1],
      LinTicks[-.002, .002, .002, 1]},
    YGapSizes -> .1, XGapSizes -> .05,
    YPanelSizes -> {1, 1},
    XPanelSizes -> {1},
    First -> "A",
    Order -> Vertical
    ],
   FigurePanel[{1, 1}],
   RawGraphics@
    ListPlot[md1, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> Black],
   ScaledLabel[{0.085, .86}, "\[ScriptCapitalD]1"],
   FigurePanel[{2, 1}],
   RawGraphics@
    ListPlot[md2, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> Black],
   ScaledLabel[{0.085, .85}, "\[ScriptCapitalD]2"]
   },
  ImageSize -> 500
  ]
 ]
```

This produces the image
[image: Sample leveScheme graphic]

Comment: Nice, but perhaps you should set the vertical span to be the same in both graphics. This will make it easier to compare the two functions. The first one is literally flattened by the scale. `YPlotRanges -> {{1.48, 1.52}, {-.02, .02}}` should do it.

Comment: @Peltio: Of course, this is easy to do (set numbers for YplotRanges & YFrameTicks appropriately).  It's just as easy to change the density of ticks on any of the axes.  The salient point was that LevelScheme provides a straightforward means to a high-quality end at a great price.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution that worked for me (besides using `Grid[]` that @JasonB suggested) is to set `ImageSize->Full` in `genPlot[]`. According to the docs this means "fill out the enclosing region". Then, use `ImageSize->600` or whatever value to `GraphicsRow`. As the container increases in size, the contained cells follow because they try to fill in all the region.

[image]

Comment: `AspectRatio -> Full` can sometimes also be useful in these situations.

Comment: I believe the minimal and best solution is [per my suggestion here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162884/53366).  Does it work for you?

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the variety of good formatting alternatives presented in the answers here, I suspect that the problem comes from the `PlotLegends` option, which causes the output to have the head `Legended` instead of `Graphics`.

```
Head /@ {plot1, plot2}
(* {Legended, Legended} *)
```

Further `Legended` has its own `DisplayFunction` that I suspect interferes with its display in `GraphicsRow`.  `GraphicsRow` uses `Inset` to align graphics inside another `Graphics`.  I have occasionally but rarely found that `Inset` does not play nice with some objects, but I've never been able to fully understand why.

If you use `PlotLabel` instead of `PlotLegends`, the plots can be shown in `GraphicsRow`.  If you need `PlotLegends`, then adapt one of the other answers.

```
genPlot[c_, dat_, ymin_, ymax_, legend_] := 
 ListPlot[{Table[c, {Length[dat]}], dat}, AxesLabel -> {"N", "\[Mu]"},
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {ymin, ymax}}, PlotLabel -> legend, Joined -> True, 
   Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ImageSize -> 400]

plot1 = genPlot[3/2, meandatf1, 1.45, 1.55, "\[ScriptCapitalD]1"];
plot2 = genPlot[0, meandatf2, -0.004, 0.004, "\[ScriptCapitalD]2"];

GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is the most effective abd elegant solution to "ugly" or rasterized text in graphics.  This also works for `Plot3D` `ListPointPlot3D` etc.

**Note:** Also this improves the output of `MaTeX[]` [available here](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html)

```
ggrough = Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}];
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "rough.pdf", ggrough]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "rough.svg", ggrough]

ggsmooth=Graphics[Inset[gg], ImageSize->{UpTo[900], UpTo[1100]}, AspectRatio -> Full]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "smooth.pdf", ggsmooth]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "smooth.svg", ggsmooth]
```

[image: Rough notebook display]
[image: Smooth notebook display]

While there is a discernible difference in the MMA Notebook display, enlarging makes the distinction clearer.  **Note the change of font**:

- Rough PDF and SVG:  [image: Rough PDF] and [image]
- Smooth PDF and SVG: [image: Smooth PDF] and [image]