# Plotting two functions in one graph

Tags: graphics

```
Plot[2x, {x,0,4}]
Plot[x^2, {x,10,12}]
```

How do I merge these two graphs into one graph without the range `{4,10}`?

Comment: You've seen `Show[]`?

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned. Why not choosing a meaningful name?

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Comment: Alright, I've linked to a different duplicate. It should not be too hard to adapt the solutions in the linked dupe to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs.

```
Show[
 Plot[2 x, {x, 0, 4}],
  Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 12}]
 ]
```

OR

```
  Plot[{2 x, x^2}, {x, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: If my reading of the question is correct, the OP doesn't want the parts in the interval $(4,10)$ to show up.

Comment: @J.M.isback. corrected, thanks

Comment: @J.M.isback.: Yes, how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @hvphuc, did you already look up the thing I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: @J.M.isback. Thank you for your answer, I have read the thing you suggested. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @hvphuc, so `Show[Plot[2 x, {x, 0, 4}], Plot[x^2, {x, 10, 12}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, Automatic}]` is not what you want?

Comment: @J.M.isback. No, I want the parts in the interval (0,4) and (10,12), the range (4,10) not to show up in the picture. Could you help me to solve it?

Comment: @hvphuc In two separate plots? same plot with broken axes? Is there an example you can point?  We are willing to help, but you don't explain thoroughly what your needs are. You need to help us to help you. You should have explained properly on the first instance on your original question.

Comment: I am so sorry @rhermans, my question is not clear. I want to plot two functions in the same figure with the broken x-axes. I understand that all you try to help us. I am sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: @hvphuc  Something like this but in the horizontal axis?  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35207/10397

Comment: @rhermans. Thanks for the answers, although not in the x-axis, it is useful. But I hoped there where someway around it, and I think I will go for it. Thanks for the help.