# How to plot multiple lines simultaneously in a single figure?

Tags: plotting

For example, suppose I want to plot $\sin(x)$ and $x^2 +4 $ as two lines simultaneously in a single figure.

I know Show can do it.

But what if I have 5 lines to plot?

Is there anyway to evade Show? I know in Matlab it is very simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting two functions in one graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97031/plotting-two-functions-in-one-graph)

Comment: second example on the documentation of plot...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to evade Show? I know in Matlab it is very simple

You do not need to use `Show`, just use `Plot` with the functions to plot in a list.

```
 Plot[{Sin[x],x^2+4},{x,- Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> The problem with this method is that, you need an explicit expression
>   of the function. What if you just have some data?

```
data1={1,2,3,4,5};
data2={1.3,2.4,4.3,5.2};
ListLinePlot[{data1,data2},Mesh->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The problem with this method is that, you need an explicit expression of the function. What if you just have some data?

Comment: @S. Kohn, so why did you neglect to mention that in your question?