# Problem with combining the plot of two functions with different independent variables

Tags: plotting

I want to plot two functions with different independent variables in one Plot.

The code below plots my functions in two different plots.

```
a = 0.67
b = 0.33
p=1
YB=(B* p)/a
YZ=(Z* p)/b
Plot[YB,{B,0,10}, PlotLabels ->"Y=(B* p)/0.67"]
Plot[YZ,{Z,0,10}, PlotLabels ->"Y=(Z* p)/0.33"]
```

How should I modify this code so that the plots be combined into one plot?

Comment: Define them as functions first: `Clear[yb]; yb[b_] := b p / 67` and do the same with `yz[z_] := ...` then plot them as function of the same variable. Or alternatively combine the two plots with `Show[Plot[...], Plot[...]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
YB = (B*p)/a;
YZ = (Z*p)/b;
labels = {"YB = (B*p)/a", "YZ = (p*Z)/b"};
p1 = Plot[bb, {bb, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotLabels -> labels[[1]]];
p2 = Plot[2*aa, {aa, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red,PlotLabels -> labels[[2]]];

Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The result is this:

[image]

The following links are useful:

[How to | Combine Two or More Graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CombineTwoOrMoreGraphics.html)

[Plotting two functions in one graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97031/plotting-two-functions-in-one-graph)

[Wolfram documentation for Show[...]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

Comment: `PlotLabels` is an option to `Plot`, not `Graphics`, so it doesn't do anything inside of `Show`.

Comment: There is a problem with using PlotLabels as an argument of Show I have asked a question about it and I will correct the answer as soon as possible.https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259384/problem-with-using-plotlabels-or-plotlegends-as-an-option-for-show

Comment: I have edited the answer. but still one of the labels are not shown. I asked the problem here:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259386/labels-not-shown-in-a-plot

Comment: I have finalized my answer and it works now.

Comment: Your solution was exactly what I wanted, I am really sorry for the moderator who found my answer off topic, I am really new to Mathematica, so I would appreciate if anybody would improve my question.