# Problem with using PlotLabels or PlotLegends as an option for Show[]

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

As mentioned in the documentation for `Show[]`:

> Show allows any option that can be applied to graphics to be given.

I have the following code:

```
p1 = Plot[bb, {bb, 0, 5}];
p2 = Plot[2*aa, {aa, 0, 10}];
Show[p1, p2, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}, PlotLabels -> labels]
```

This is the result:

[image]

Why the `PlotLabels` and `PlotStyle` (and also `PlotLegends` if used) are not applied to the plots `p1` and `p2` and how can I use them as an argument in `Show[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Same solution as I made in your previous question.

```
p1 = Plot[{bb, 2*bb}, {bb, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

In the specified plot range, you don't need the `Show[...]`