# Inset an image into Graphic just large enough to hold it

Tags: graphics, export

The following example data is from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35193/53366).

**The problem:** To get the image inset into a Graphic object just large enough to hold the inset image.

The Inset technique was suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92137/53366).

The context is that Labels are often exported rasterized and of poor quality.
This is especially true in the case of 3D graphics.

The solution to these is to `Graphics[Inset[yourimg]]` when you export to PDF or SVG, which gives all labels etc. as vectorized.

Particularly powerful when you use [MaTeX to produce publication quality graphics](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html)

```
meandatf1 = {1.48908, 1.49641, 1.49354, 1.50385, 1.49835, 1.49617, 
1.50569, 1.50117, 1.50226, 1.50151, 1.50108, 1.50031, 1.49955, 
1.49721, 1.49898, 1.50266, 1.50177, 1.50227, 1.49886, 1.50002}

meandatf2 = {-0.00127783, 0.000556012, 
0.0000143709, -0.000602328, -0.000375952, -0.00125357, 0.0000228143,
0.000175103, 0.000868018, -0.0003298, 0.000230178, 
0.000222689, -0.0000624273, -0.0000760139, -0.000263302, 
0.0000826082, 0.000206463, 0.0000507921, -0.0000955452, 
0.000184107}
genPlot[c_, dat_, ymin_, ymax_, legend_] := 
ListPlot[{Table[c, {Length[dat]}], dat}, AxesLabel -> {"N", "\[Mu]"},
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {ymin, ymax}}, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Above], Joined -> True, Mesh -> None, 
InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ImageSize -> 400] (*I tried also without ImageSize,see below*)

plot1 = genPlot[3/2, meandatf1, 1.45, 1.55, "\[ScriptCapitalD]1"];
plot2 = genPlot[0, meandatf2, -0.004, 0.004, "\[ScriptCapitalD]2"];

gg = Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}];
Graphics[Inset[gg, Automatic, Automatic,Scaled[1]], ImageSize -> {800, 400}]
```

Appreciate hints and tips.

Comment: maybe  adding the options `ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}`,  (or `ImageSize -> {800, Automatic}`) and  `AspectRatio -> 1/3`?

Comment: Hmm, thanks.  It looks like playing with AspectRatio alone is enough, and simplifies the export method to:`Graphics[Inset[gg], AspectRatio -> 1/3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hat-tip to @kglr's comment:

I believe this is both the minimal solution and provides the best output:
**Note:** there are subtleties when exporting that do not show in the notebook output, hence the need for the size arguments.

```
ggrough = Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "rough.pdf", ggrough]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "rough.svg", ggrough]

ggsmooth = Graphics[Inset[gg], ImageSize -> {UpTo[900], UpTo[1100]}, AspectRatio -> 1/3]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "smooth.pdf", ggsmooth]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "smooth.svg", ggsmooth]
```

[image: Rough notebook cell]
[image: Smooth notebook cel]

Check the SVG and PDF contents produced by the Export code above and you'll see the subtle differences.